# How to export assets from Adobe XD to PNG, SVG, etc?

Tags: adobe, assets, figma, adobe-xd

I am familiar with Figma, but new to Adobe XD.
I got a link for Adobe XD design from designer and I am able to inspect the style(css properties).
But, not sure how to export assets like icons, images.
I use chrome browser, not XD app to see the design.

Answer (score 0):

Tow ways:

1. There is a plugin to export all the images (png, svg, ...etc)
2. By following these steps:

   a- Select the requested element.

   b- Right click on mouse.

   c- Choose "File" on the top bar. then click export.